# Как разместить окно программы по центру экрана не зная разрешения?

Tags: qt

Как разместить окно программы по центру на любом мониторе не зная разрешения в Qt. На одномониторной системе.

Comment: вопрос непонятен

Comment: Запуск окна по центру монитора не зная разрешения экрана в Qt.

Comment: На любом мониторе в многомониторной системе, или на любой одномониторной системе? дополните вопрос, кнопка "править"

Comment: в Qt можно получить разрешение см. QDesktopWidget. Перемещение окна надо встроить в обработку showEvent, т.е. когда будет известна толщина рамки окна

Comment: QDesktopWidget устарел, в справочной документации не рекомендуется его использовать.

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант:

```
MainWindow w;
//Окно программы растянуть на весь монитор
w.showFullScreen(); 
//получить его размер, равный размеру монитора
const auto screenSize = w.size(); 
//вернуть обычный размер
w.showNormal(); 
//переместить в центр
w.move(screenSize.width()/2 - w.size().width()/2, 
       screenSize.height()/2 - w.size().height()/2);
```

Comment: Работает код:
w.setGeometry
    (
        QStyle::alignedRect
        (
             Qt::LeftToRight,
             Qt::AlignCenter,
             w.size(),
             a.screenAt(w.pos())->availableGeometry()
        )
    );